# Flow rate into a reactor from feed

Tags: chemical-engineering, flow-control

I have a fresh feed (stream 1) entering a reactor . This fresh feed consists 225kg/h of iso-butane , 225kg/h of butylenes and 
50kg/h of n-butane .

In the stream table I need to add in a flowrate value . How do I calculate this ? Do I take the average ?

And also the composition (wt%) how do I calculate them ?

Do I calculate the percentage ? 
This means iso-butane and butylenes have 45% each and 10% for the n-butane in the mixed fresh feed .

This is a question I have to solve . I'm not given wt% . So can I calculate the wt% by knowing the flowrate of all the products in the fresh feed ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, weight percent of a component is the mass (flow rate) of that component divided by the total mass (total flow rate). Total flow rate is equal to the sum of the flowrates of every component.